# Email Validation using Python Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, validation, email-validation

I have 9 email patterns. I expect:

- myname@domainemail.com
- my.name@domainemail.com
- my.name1@domainemail.com
- my_name.1@domainemail.com
  are valid emails.

and

- my-name@domainemail.com
- my.name.1@domainemail.com
- domainname.1@domainemail.com
- 1myname@domainemail.com
- 1.myname@domainemail.com
  are not valid emails.

Then, I have made script of regex like:

```
regex = r"(^[a-zA-Z_]+[\.]?[a-z0-9]+)@([\w.]+\.[\w.]+)$"
```

But, email domainname.1@domainemail.com is still valid.

How to make the right pattern regex so that email become not valid, and all of email patterns can fit to my expectation?

Comment: Maybe `^(?![a-zA-Z]+\.\d+@)[a-zA-Z_]+(?:\.[a-z0-9]+)?@[\w.]+\.\w+$` will do, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xp0YVx/2/).

Comment: Perhaps with an optional part matching the underscore or start the match with a-z before the dot `^[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)|\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?@\w+(?:\.\w+)+` https://regex101.com/r/Q3TxQc/1

Answer (score 1):

For the example data you could either match an optional part with underscores where a dot followed by a digit is allowed before the @

Or you match a part that with a dot and a char a-z before the @

```
 ^[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+|\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ times a char a-z
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+` Repeat 1+ times an underscore followed by a char a-z or digit 0-9
  - `\.[A-Za-z0-9]+` Match a dot and 1+ chars a-z or digit 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*` Match a a dot and a single char a-z and 0+ chars a-z or digits
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `@` Match literally
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)*` Repeat 0+ times a-z0-9 followed by a dot
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}` Match a-z0-9 2 or more times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9tb9M3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex pattern with `gmi` flags:

```
^[a-z]+(?:(?:\.[a-z]+)+\d*|(?:_[a-z]+)+(?:\.\d+)?)?@(?!.*\.\.)[^\W_][a-z\d.]+[a-z\d]{2}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/xoVprE/4